unit tests of methods that seek permission to use GPS in Flutter/Dart
I'm trying to do unit tests of this code below but without success. I'm not able to cover the setState() codes, even using GeolocatorPlatform.
       class _ClassHomeView extends StatefulWidget {
      const _ClassDiaryHomeView();
    
     
      @override
      _ClassHomeState createState() => _ClassHomeState();
    }
    
    
    
    class _ClassHomeState extends State<_ClassHomeView> {
          bool _isGpsDisable = false;
          bool _hasPermission = false;
          StreamSubscription<ServiceStatus>? _serviceStatusStreamSubscription;
        
        
          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            _checkPermissionAndGpsStatus();
            _listenToGpsStatus();
          }
        
        Future<void> _checkPermissionAndGpsStatus() async {
            final permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
        
            if (permission == LocationPermission.always ||
                permission == LocationPermission.whileInUse) {
              setState(() {
                _hasPermission = true;
              });
        
              final isGpsEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
              setState(() {
                _isGpsDisable = !isGpsEnabled;
              });
            } else {
              setState(() {
                _hasPermission = false;
              });
            }
          }
        
          @override
          void dispose() {
            _serviceStatusStreamSubscription?.cancel();
            super.dispose();
          }
        
          void _listenToGpsStatus() {
            _serviceStatusStreamSubscription =
                Geolocator.getServiceStatusStream().listen((ServiceStatus status) {
              setState(() {
                _isGpsDisable = status == ServiceStatus.disabled;
              });
            });
          }

          Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
        

              //continue....  

                                 
                       }

                   }

I was trying something like this:
class MockGeolocatorPlatform extends Mock implements GeolocatorPlatform {}

void main() {
  late MockGeolocatorPlatform mockGeolocatorPlatform;
  late StreamController<ServiceStatus> serviceStatusStreamController;

  setUp(() {
    mockGeolocatorPlatform = MockGeolocatorPlatform();
    serviceStatusStreamController = StreamController<ServiceStatus>();

    GeolocatorPlatform.instance = mockGeolocatorPlatform;
  });

  tearDown(() {
    serviceStatusStreamController.close();
    reset(mockGeolocatorPlatform);
  });

  testWidgets('_listenToGpsStatus updates state on GPS status change', 
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    when(() => mockGeolocatorPlatform.getServiceStatusStream())
        .thenAnswer((_) => serviceStatusStreamController.stream);

    await tester.pumpWidget(const MaterialApp(home: ClassHomePage()));

    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      final state = tester.state<_ClassHomeState>(
          find.byType(_ClassHomeView));

      state._listenToGpsStatus();

    
      serviceStatusStreamController.add(ServiceStatus.disabled);
      await tester.pump();

      expect(state._isGpsDisable, true);

    
      serviceStatusStreamController.add(ServiceStatus.enabled);
      await tester.pump();

      expect(state._isGpsDisable, false);
    });

    
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  });
}

Even when I stop using ''_'' in the names, it doesn't work, it returns several types of errors, from lack of initialization to expect error. Any suggestions?
